# Database error in django while running local sever?

Tags: python, django

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
>   Did you install mysqlclient?

Getting this error even installed the mysqlclient
python version: `Python 3.6.9`

Answer (score 0):

You have to install mysqlclient in the virtual environment using `pip install mysqlclient`.

Comment: mysqlclient==1.4.6
This is displaying when I done pip3 freeze

Comment: It can be a configuration error. Please check your credentials or if MySQL is running or not.

Comment: Yes the credentials are coorect mysql is running

Comment: Can you verify that you can connect to it over a certain port? And Django is configured to connect over that specific port with the right credentials?